# Why generated parser issues syntax error?

Tags: c, grammar, bison, yacc, lex

I am trying to write a simple grammar which accepts statements of the form

```
     7 = var int
     9 = abc float
```

But with the following LEX and YACC code, the generated parser issues syntax error (Calls yyerror)

LEX :---

```
[0-9]+      { yylval.num = atof(yytext); return NUM; }
"int"       return INT;
"float"     return FLOAT;
[a-z]+      {  yylval.str = strdup(yytext); return ID; }
\n              /* Ignore end of lines */
[ \t]+          /* Ignore white spaces and tabs */
```

YACC:---

```
%% 
commands: /* empty */
    | commands command
    ;                                                                                     

command:                                                                                  
    int_exp
    |                                                                                     
    float_exp
    ;                                                                                     

int_exp: exp INT                                                                        
    ;                                          

float_exp: exp FLOAT
    ;

exp : NUM '=' ID
    ;

%%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a token for `'='` in your lex file and use its terminal symbol name instead of `'='` in your grammar definition.

```
[0-9]+      { yylval.num = atof(yytext); return NUM; }
"int"       return INT;
"float"     return FLOAT;
[a-z]+      {  yylval.str = strdup(yytext); return ID; }
\n              /* Ignore end of lines */
[ \t]+          /* Ignore white spaces and tabs */
"="         return ASSIGN;
```

```
exp : NUM ASSIGN ID
    ;
```

Comment: It's not necessary to define a symbolic constant, and practices vary there, but yes, there needs to be a rule to return a token for `=` (which can be `'='`).

Comment: You can have a character class for these then return yytext[0]